# How to set button position in the bottom of div using Tailwind CSS

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I want to set individul card button on the bottom of div but also all card item title will be single or dubble line also

I want to set individul card button on the bottom of div but also all card item title will be single or dubble line also but i cant do that properly

[enter image description here](https://i.ibb.co/WDR8V8H/code.png)

```
    <div className='w-full lg:w-1/4 bg-white rounded-xl p-6'>
      <h2 className='text-blue-500 text-lg font-bold leading-7 mb-4'>
        Credit Hour Remaining 7 hr
      </h2>
      <hr className='border-[#1C1B1B33] mb-4' />
      <h2 className='text-[#1C1B1B] text-xl font-bold'>Course Name</h2>
      <ul className='my-5'>
        {selectedCourses.map((course, ind) => {
          return (
            <li key={course.course_id}>
              {ind + 1} {course.course_title}
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
      <hr className='border-[#1C1B1B33]' />
      <h3 className='my-5 text-[#1C1B1BCC] text-4 font-medium'>
        Total Credit Hour : {13}
      </h3>
      <hr className='border-[#1C1B1B33] mb-4' />
      <h3 className=' text-[#1C1B1BCC] text-4 font-medium'>
        Total Price : 48000 USD
      </h3>
    </div>
```

Comment: It seems like you may have omitted too much code. I can't quite see any code that would be the cards or the *Select* button in your screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The code provided is **different** from the screenshot, anyway I suggest two ways one on the button and other for description.

*Button*: use `mt-auto` to set an auto top margin.

*Description*: use `h-auto` to force the height push the button to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

As the others said, the code that you provided is not related to what you want on the screenshots.

However, if you want to "stick" the buttons on the bottom of each card, you just need to wrap the content, except the button, in a div and add some classes.

```html
<div class="flex flex-col gap-4 rounded bg-white p-4">
  <div class="flex-1">
    <h2>Intro</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsuus eos laboriosam.</p>
  </div>
  <button>Select</button>
</div>
```

You can check the code here: https://play.tailwindcss.com/MHbcPAeMsU?layout=horizontal